# Add class to Checked = True Input

Tags: jquery, select, input, shopify, checked

So I have a drop-down selection of a product. And I just want to be able to add a class when the input is checked.  I know that with css you can recognize the input:checked but I need an extra for further development.
This is part of my code

```
for (var i=0,length=variant.options.length; i<length; i++) {
    var radioButton = $productForm.find('.swatch[data-option-index="' + escape(i) + '"] :radio[value="' + variant.options[i].replace(/\"/g,'\\"') +'"]');
    if (radioButton.length) {
      radioButton.get(0).checked = true;
    }
  }
```

And I tried to add the class in this way:

```
if (radioButton.length) {
      radioButton.get(0).checked = true.addClass("selected");;
}
```

And in this way

```
if (radioButton.length) {
      radioButton.get(0).checked = true;
      radioButton.get(0).addClass("selected");
}
```

Neither of this ways work, I can't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't work as you're mixing javascript and jquery - yes jquery *is* javascript, but it has its own methods that apply to jquery objects, one of which is `.addClass()`.

So this code:

```
var radioButton = $productForm.find(...
```

returns a jquery object, while:

```
radioButton.get(0)
```

gives the original DOM object, which does not have an `.addClass()` method.

You can use `.addClass` without using `.get(0)` as in:

```
radioButton.addClass("selected");
```